# Current element being appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm breaking my head trying to do this.
How can i get the current element being appended by the append method of jQuery?
I know it will append to every element on the set, but there is no way to get the current element being iterated?

Lets say we have this HTML

```
<div class="parent" id="1">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent" id="2">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
... more dynamically generated parents
```

Each div is generated with another append call earlier, so I don't think this is important, but I'll leave the info just in case.

jQuery

```
$(".list").append('<input name="id[IDOFPARENT][]"/>');
```

Here I append the input to every box, but it should contain the parent's id (so far i used just a static id.

I've tried with

```
$(this).closest(".parent").attr("id")
```

But it says `undefined` because `this` is:

```
Window {speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis, caches: CacheStorage, localStorage: Storage, sessionStorage: Storage, webkitStorageInfo: DeprecatedStorageInfo…}
```

(the document i guess).

There is any way to resolve it without having to switch to a "foreach" loop?

Comment: $(".list") will return you an array iterate over it and for each elements append html

Comment: yup, one of the things i didn't wanted to do was to switch to a foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each element you get by the class name as `$('.list')` gives you an array. For iterating you can use the `.each()` function

```js
$(function(){
  $(".list").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.parent').attr('id');
    var html = '<input name="id_' + id + '"/>'
    $(this).append(html);
  })
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="1">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent" id="2">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent" id="3">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent" id="4">
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Despite i don't want to switch to a foreach/each loop, this is the cleanest way to do it. Said that, it will not work for my specific use case, but it will work as answer to my question unless something else comes up.

Comment: my logic is faulty and using this will cause it to rewrite every input every time i add a new "parent". i'll have to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = $(".counter").length; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).on("click",function(){ //on add input button click
        //alert("masuk klikc")
        //e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment

            $(wrapper).append('<div class="counter"><div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="perluDilakukanTindakan">Tindakan Perbaikan Yang Perlu Dilakukan '+x+' :</label><div class="controls">'
                    +'<textarea name="perluDilakukanTindakan" cols="" rows="" id="perluDilakukanTindakan" style="margin-left: 20px; width: 350px;"></textarea></div>'
                    +'</div>'


                    +'<div class="control-group">'
                    +'<div class="controls">'
                    +'<label class="control-label">Label Detail '+x+' :</label>'
                    +'&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Delete Detail Perbaikan" class="remove_field btn btn-mini btn-danger" style="margin-top: 4px;">'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'</div>'


                    +'<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="sDeadlinePerbaikan">Detail Att '+x+' :</label><div class="controls">'

                    +'<input type="text" name="stringDeadlinePerbaikan" id="sDeadlinePerbaikan'+x+'" value="" class="sDeadlinePerbaikan fieldShort"></div>'
                    +'</div></div>'); //add input box
        }

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
```

html

```
<div id="input_fields_wrap">
                <div class="counter">
                    <input type="textarea" name="perluDilakukanTindakan" id="perluDilakukanTindakan" label="Tindakan Perbaikan Yang Perlu Dilakukan 1 " labelSeparator=":" cssStyle="margin-left: 20px; width: 350px;" /> 

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label class="control-label">PIC Tindakan Perbaikan 1 :</label>
                            <input type="text" cssClass="textFieldBranchCode"
                                id="picTindakanPerbaikan" name="picTindakanPerbaikan"
                                cssStyle="margin-left:20px;" labelposition="left"
                                labelSeparator="" theme="simple"  readonly="true"/>

                            <input type="text" id="namaLengkapTindakanPerbaikan"
                                name="namaLengkapTindakanPerbaikan" label=""
                                labelposition="left" labelSeparator="" theme="simple"
                                readonly="true" cssStyle="margin-left:0px;" />

                        <input type="button" value="Add Detail Perbaikan " id="add_field_button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" style="margin-top: 4px;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <input type="text" name="stringDeadlinePerbaikan" id="stringDeadlinePerbaikan" label="Label detail 1 " labelSeparator=":" cssClass="sDeadlinePerbaikan fieldShort" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is my dynamic js that i've implemented, this script will be append "html" in the last element. if you need to append the current element that you want, just modify the "html text" to element on the screen that you've chosen.